# Tibet Xizang Travel: How to stay safe traveling alone

Tags: safety, tibet

I heard that Tibet is an awesome place and I am considering going after I am done traveling in Kunming.

However, I would be traveling alone (ie any friends will be friends I meet there rather than from previous places). I heard this is somewhat dangerous due to the political problems Tibet is facing right now. What kind of travel groups do you recommend joining to see Tibet. I've researched and heard mixed reviews on all sorts of travel groups. Ideally, I would prefer not going with a travel group, but I don't know if that is an option.

I wanted to check out the Potala palace, Rongbuk Monastery, and other attractions (I haven't done much research yet, but I heard the sights in Tibet were breathtaking). I just want to see the best sights. I'm not that interested in Tibet apart from learning basic culture and learning a couple phrases to say to locals to show appreciation. I also heard NOT to speak any Chinese while there due to political tension.

Comment: I thought you had to be part of a tour to go there.

Comment: Oh yes you are right. I guess I should say I want to be on the more laid back travel tour. Any good Tibet tour group recommendations?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was originally about something impossible, and is now asking for recommendations, which is off-topic.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Well citizens of PRC can travel freely in Tibet. [So far we don't think citizens of any other country have been granted an exception.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78873) You can also go "alone" in that you can be a tour group of one person, but every tour group must have a tour guide, so you'll never actually be alone if you're not a Chinese citizen.